# TypeError: props.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

**BottomMissionText.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { Center, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import IMissionText from "../../interfaces/AboutPage/IMissionText";

//Simple bottom mission text component
export default function BottomMissionText(props: Array<IMissionText>) {
    return (
        <Center pt={5}>
            {props.map((i) => (
                <Text>{i.title}</Text>
            ))}
        </Center>
    );
}
```

**IMissionText.ts**

```
export default interface IMissionText {
    title: string;
    text: string;
}
```

**MissionBox.tsx(snippet)**

```
<Box>
    {isT !== false ? (
       <BottomMissionText {...traditionalStatement} />
    ) : null}
    {isL !== false ? (
    <BottomMissionText {...traditionalStatement} />
    ) : null}
</Box>
```

I've been trying this for almost two hours now, and I keep getting this error (title).

Comment: How does `traditionalStatement` looks ?

Comment: I think in order to use functional component props, you must use an object with keys / values that can be mapped to attributes in your JSX elements

Comment: Props is not array, it is Object. So you can't use methods of array :)

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. To pass in multiple objects like I wish to what should i do?

Comment: keep them in an array and don't spread them?

Comment: "To pass in multiple objects like I wish to what should i do?" Pass each as a prop individually. Make sure you've defined the correct props interface. Please share what `traditionalStatement` is so we can better suggest how to pass it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass multiple objects, inside your MissionBox.tsx you should define traditionalStatement as an array of objects

```
const traditionalStatement: IMissionText[] = [
    {
        title: "your title1 string",
        text: "your text1 string",
    },
    {
        title: "your title2 string",
        text: "your text2 string",
    }
]

// ... rest of your component's code

<Box>
    {isT !== false ? (
       <BottomMissionText traditionalStatement=traditionalStatement />
    ) : null}
    {isL !== false ? (
    <BottomMissionText traditionalStatement=traditionalStatement />
    ) : null}
</Box>
```

In the functional component, you need to define the schema of props. I have named it `IBottomMissionTextProps`. And then de-structure the `traditionalStatement` from props in the functional component like the below code. Or directly use `props.traditionalStatement` in map.

```
import React from "react";
import { Center, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import IMissionText from "../../interfaces/AboutPage/IMissionText";

interface IBottomMissionTextProps {
    traditionalStatement: IMissionText[];
}

//Simple bottom mission text component
export default function BottomMissionText(props: IBottomMissionTextProps) {
    const { traditionalStatement } = props; // destructuring
    // alternatively, you can use 
    // const traditionalStatement = props.traditionalStatement;

    return (
        <Center pt={5}>
            {traditionalStatement.map((i) => (
                <Text>{i.title}</Text>
            ))}
        </Center>
    );
}
```